# Google Maps Android API v2 tutorial doesnt show anything

Tags: android, google-maps

First of all, my apologies as I know I am asking something very basic and might be stupid but basic google maps on android brought me on my knees.

I am using https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start as the starting point for learning google maps. Though I have managed to get rid of exceptions and other hurdles to get the app running, I am not seeing any map as such in the UI. I just see google written in the bottom left. I have shared the project at Github https://github.com/abhinavtyagi/MapsM.git and my logcat output is given below. I am using Android Studio. I am using Nexus4 in Genymotion with Android 5.0 and have used minimum sdk ver as 4.2 in project

```
05-16 16:42:58.489    4265-4265/? I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
05-16 16:42:58.562    4265-4265/com.chronos.mapsm I/zzy﹕ Making Creator dynamically
05-16 16:42:58.573    4265-4265/com.chronos.mapsm W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
05-16 16:42:58.576    4265-4265/com.chronos.mapsm W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
05-16 16:42:58.618    4265-4265/com.chronos.mapsm I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services client version: 7327000
05-16 16:42:58.620    4265-4265/com.chronos.mapsm I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services package version: 7329470
05-16 16:42:58.723    4265-4304/com.chronos.mapsm D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
05-16 16:42:58.726    4265-4265/com.chronos.mapsm D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xabbd7130, tid 4265
05-16 16:42:58.730    4265-4265/com.chronos.mapsm D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
05-16 16:42:58.754    4265-4304/com.chronos.mapsm D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
05-16 16:42:58.754    4265-4304/com.chronos.mapsm D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
05-16 16:42:58.759    4265-4304/com.chronos.mapsm D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
05-16 16:42:58.766    4265-4304/com.chronos.mapsm D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaf60b760, tid 4304
05-16 16:42:58.774    4265-4304/com.chronos.mapsm I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-16 16:42:58.794    4265-4304/com.chronos.mapsm D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-16 16:42:58.825    4265-4304/com.chronos.mapsm W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-16 16:42:58.825    4265-4304/com.chronos.mapsm W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaf607f20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-16 16:42:58.892    4265-4300/com.chronos.mapsm D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaf40b6c0, tid 4300
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check my implementation of Google Maps: [github repo](https://github.com/dimitardanailov/grada.me)

1. You need to read -> [README.md](http://README.md)
2. After that, you need to install google maps in Gradle file: [gradle.app](https://github.com/dimitardanailov/grada.me/blob/master/app/build.gradle)
3. Add all necessary permission for Application : [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/dimitardanailov/grada.me/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

Note:

Please visit google API console https://code.google.com/apis/console and generate a new Google Maps and replace my key:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />
```

4. Follow my instructions for implementation of Google Maps: [GradaMeMainActivity.java](https://github.com/dimitardanailov/grada.me/blob/master/app/src/main/java/grada/me/GradaMeMainActivity.java)

Final Result:

[image: Google Maps screenshot from application]

Note: if you have any questions, please contact me.

Comment: I am not able to see a basic map implementation which i could have forked. What you have mentioned is essentially listed on google's startup page i mentioned and I am not seeing desired result. The KEY is provided, app.gradle mentions to compile maps 7.3.0, permissions are there (more than enough) but still no luck :(

Comment: I not understand what the problem with my implementation ?

Comment: I cloned the repo but again it was same. I just moved to compileSdkVersion to 22 and few modifications like play services version  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.3.0' but it is all same. Here is what i see http://i59.tinypic.com/xkras1.jpg
Can you update it to latest sdk/services?

Comment: I change google play services version from 6 to 7. Can you try again ?

Comment: I get following things in logcat:


05-17 11:59:42.844  14784-14784/grada.me D/grada.me.GradaMeMainActivity﹕ onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = 4


05-17 12:00:01.959  14784-14805/grada.me E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).


May be key or some other problem. I tried it in My Xperia M2 running Kitkat and there also, the end product was same. I will debug and find out what the error is for but wanted to ask if you have tried it recently (running?)

Comment: @Abhinav you need to change my key. Please go in Google API console and generate a new Android API key and replace my key  `<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />`

Comment: @Abhinav please read again Point 3. I add more explanation how to avoid authentication issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78034/discussion-between-d-danailov-and-abhinav).

Comment: @Abhinav What happen ?

Comment: I am not really sure but things started working again. I will try to see what was it shortly and will post it